# embed a part of a website to another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to use/add the free map tools which I found on this site http://www.freemaptools.com/how-far-is-it-between.htm to my current websites which are a list of tools that are commonly used by our staff, I was planning to embbed it, however it doesn't seem to have that kind of feature, and I am asking you guys if you can offer me an alternative to the task that I want to do. While doing this "ToolBox" I am also willing to make my own map tools that measures the distance between countries. If you can kindly guide me. Thank you. Here's what I've got so far

Code:

```
<form name="inp">
<table align="center" width="95%" border="0">
<tbody><tr>
    <td width="30"></td>
    <td align="right">City, Country</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>City, Country</td>
    <td width="30"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="30"></td>
 <td width="269" align="right">From 
<input name="pointa" type="text" value="" size="22" onkeypress="autocompletea(this.value, event)"></td>
<td width="34"><div align="center">to</div></td>
<td width="271"><input name="pointb" type="text" value="" size="22" onkeypress="autocompleteb(this.value, event)"> <input name="show" type="button" value="Show" onclick="findaandb(document.forms['inp']['pointa'].value,document.forms['inp']['pointb'].value);">
  <label></label></td>
<td width="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<div id="autocompletediva" class="autocomp" style="display: block; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;"></div>
</td>
<td></td>
<td colspan="2">
<div id="autocompletedivb" class="autocomp" style="display: block; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5"><div id="msg" class="msg">&nbsp;</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center"> Measure in :
<input name="dist" type="radio" onclick="toggleUnits('MILES');" checked="CHECKED">
<font face="verdana, geneva, helvetica" size="2">miles<input type="radio" name="dist" onclick="toggleUnits('KMS');">
 km</font>
</td>
</tr>

<tr><td colspan="5" align="center"><strong>Distance as the Crow Flies </strong> :
      <input style="display: inline;" id="distance" type="text" size="10" value="0.000" readonly="true"> 
      <img src="" alt="As the crow Flies"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center"><strong>Distance by Land Transport</strong> :
      <input style="display: inline;" id="transport" type="text" size="10" value="0.000" readonly="true">
      <img src="" alt="Land Transport"> 
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use <jsp:include> to include another page in your page. You can set the position, but it will display the whole page. Better ask the site admin for plugin as most of the map sites will have it and that's the legal way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the javascript part

```
onkeypress="autocompletea(this.value, event)"

onclick="toggleUnits('KMS');"

onclick="toggleUnits('MILES');"
```

These are all javascript function calls, but what you posted is only the HTML part. Quickly reviewing the web page you posted i think that at least you're missing the following JS file.
http://www.freemaptools.com/script/how-far-is-it-between.js

Although i think that if you are missing this, may be because it is your first time you are creating a web page,HTML is only the layout and JavaScript enables you to "dynamize" the HTML (well, i think that many will disagree but it's kind of).

I recommend you to  have a look at a JavaScript tutorial, i don't remeber any good right now, but sure that if you google for you will find many good tutorials around there.

Hope helped

Answer (score 1):

You can try "Iframe"  or Jquery "load" function.

Here are some examples

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Hope this helps....